# Concave functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given $(X,\mathcal{F},m)$ a measure space with $m(X)=1$ and $||f||_p<\infty$ for some $p>0$.  Need to show that $\forall q \in (0,p)$ $$\int \log |f| dm\leq \log(||f||_q),$$ $$  \log ||f||_q \leq \frac{\int |f|^qdm -1}{q},$$
$$\lim_{q\to 0} \frac{\int |f|^q dm -1}{q}=\int \log |f| dm$$ and finally $$\lim_{q\to 0} ||f||_q= e^{\int \log (|f|)dm} .$$  My attempt at first inequality since $\log$ is concave we have $$\int \log (|f|)dm\leq \log\left(\int|f|dm\right)$$ by Jensen's inequality.  Want to claim $$\int |f| dm \leq ||f||_q$$ but only true for $q>1$.  If I assume the previous claim then $$\int \log (|f|)dm\leq \log\left(\int|f|dm\right)\leq \log ||f||_q$$ by properties of $\log$.  For the second inequality I have no idea as well as the limits.  The limits should follow from the inequalities somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, apply Jensen's inequality as you have to the function $|f|^q$, then multiply both sides by $1/q$. We get

$$\int \log (|f|)dm = \frac{1}{q}\int \log (|f|^q)dm\leq \frac{1}{q}\log\left(\int|f|^qdm\right) = \log\left(\left(\int|f|^qdm\right)^{1/q}\right)$$

establishing the result.

---

The second inequality essentially derives from $ x - 1 - \log x \ge 0$, which is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$. You can prove this with freshman calculus.

---

The third can be established with l'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{q\to 0} \frac{\int |f|^q dm -1}{q}= \lim_{q\to 0} \frac{\int |f|^q \log|f| dm}{1} = \int \log |f| dm$$

Note that both equalities above require justification - Why $\int_X$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ commute, and why $\int_X$ and $\lim_{q \to 0}$ commute. I'll leave these to you since they arise from fundamental reasons that you either should know, or should spend time thinking about if you don't.

---

Lastly, squeeze both sides of the inequality established in the first question to finish.